# Specify TypeScript output file name format

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, typescript, typescript1.7

I need to change the TypeScript generated js file name to something else. How can I do that

For example I have `MyCompany.ClassA.ts`

It will generate `MyCompany.ClassA.js` by default

But I want `MyCompany.ClassA.generated.js`

I took a look at `.tsConfig` file but I couldn't find anything useful there.

---

ps. I am using VisualStudio2013 for Typescript and generating the js files

Answer (score 8):

To compile a single TypeScript file to .js with a custom name, use `--outFile`:

```
tsc MyCompany.ClassA.ts --outFile MyCompany.ClassA.generated.js
```

Compiling multiple files to the `.generated.js` pattern would require a bit more work. You could compile one at a time as in the `tsc` example above.

```
tsc A.ts --outFile A.generated.js
tsc B.ts --outFile B.generated.js
```

Or you could use `--outDir` to collect the compiled files under standard names, and then rename them with your own script.

```
tsc --outDir ./generated
# run script to rename ./generated/*.js to *.generated.js
```

Note that `--outFile` and `--outDir` replace `--out`, which is deprecated:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options

Answer (score 3):

The other answer here is good and comprehensive, but just to address this:

> I took a look at the .tsconfig file but I couldn't find anything useful there

You can also set the `outFile` config in your `.tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outFile": "./some/path/MyCompany.ClassA.generated.js",
    ...
  }
}
```

[See this example in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#examples)